# Can an LTL formula uniquely be represented by an expression tree?

Tags: binary-trees, linear-temporal-logic

Just like we can represent a mathematical expression uniquely with a binary expression tree, I was wondering if we could do the same for LTL formulae? Such that no two different looking LTL formula will have a same in order traversal.

Comment: An LTL formula is also a mathematical expression.

Comment: Are you familiar with context-free grammars and parse trees?

Comment: Yes. I think it can be. I just wanted to confirm.